# fill array with data from jTable

Tags: java, jtable

I am working in NetBeans IDE, langueage Java, main class is JFrame Form.

I need to get all data from JTable and fill the array with those data. Array represents Matrix.

The code is following

```
public double[][] getMatrix(JTable jt, int row, int col){
        double[][] doub=new double[row][col];

        for(int l=0;l<com;l++){
            for(int g=0;g<row;g++){
                doub[g][l]=(double) jt.getValueAt(g, l);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(jt.getValueAt(g, l)); /*The output is correct*/
        return doub;
    }
```

I have a error

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Double

So set element from table as double isnt that easy?
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> System.out.println(jt.getValueAt(g, l)); /*The output is correct*/

That is because System.out.println() invokes the toString() method of the Object.

If you want to create a double Array, then you really should be storing `Double` objects in the `TableModel`, not String representations of Double objects.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more information and examples of storing different types of data in each column in a table.